# Premature end of file between File and SAXReader

Tags: java

I am getting this exception "Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file." between lines of getting path of file and reading file using SAXReader

```
try {

        LOG.info(" start parsing ");
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();  
        File myfile = new File(fileName);   

        if (myfile.exists()) {
            document = (Document) reader.read(fileName); // getting the exception here
        }
        else {
            LOG.error(fileName + " does not exist");
            new ExceptionErrorSupport(fileName,fileName+" does not exist","ECMException",true,CONTROLLER_CONSTANTS.ECM_ERROR_DIR);
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It seems that File() is not yet closing then SAXReader reads the file already but I cannot find a way to close File() see [Why java.io.File doesn't have a close() method?](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4752266%2Fwhy-java-io-file-doesnt-have-a-close-method&ei=3S2RVJpyiuryBbbIgtgO&usg=AFQjCNHrZm9Bp30RWzF-StHWBVYutoKsiw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.dGc).

Are there any ways to avoid this exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that `File()` is not yet closing

No it doesn't. `File()` doesn't open anything, so there is nothing to close. And even if it did it wouldn't cause this exception. Your reasoning doesn't make sense.

If you got a premature end of file, it is because your input is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because the XML file you are reading is not properly formed.

That can mean a missing end tag, or even when an end of file character is not found.